# Changing the colour of a row based on a condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I want to change a particular row color of gridview based on some condition, i am using ASP.NET with c#.

I know i can use the HTMLCellPrepared method, but in my method i want to look at the values of other grids as well? Is this possible?

```
    protected void GVResults_HtmlDataCellPrepared(object sender, ASPxGridViewTableDataCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.DataColumn.FieldName == "CarrierId")
            if ( Convert.ToInt32(e.CellValue) > 0)
                e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;            
    }
```

This is the first part of the method, but i want to look at values from other grids in order to make visual changes to this grid. Problem is I dont know how to access values from other grids....

Comment: Yes it's possible however your question is too high level. Please elaborate on `some condition` and include any code you already have

Comment: @DGibbs The condition is going to be based on values from another ASPXGridView and values from 2 drop down lists. Its a bit complex but I just need to figure out how to access values from a different ASPXGridview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you to use the htmlrowprepared event for the conditional coloring of row.

According to the code you have written, below example can help you :

```
protected void GVResults_HtmlRowPrepared(object sender, ASPxGridViewTableRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowType != GridViewRowType.Data) return;
        int value = (int)e.GetValue("CarrierId");
        if (value > 0)
            e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
```

Reference:
[Changing ASPxGridView Cell and Row Color on Condition](http://developmentsolutionsjunction.blogspot.in/2011/09/changing-aspxgridview-cell-and-row.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RowDataBound` event of GridView to check a condition if your styling depends on data and set a style for that condition.

[Here is an example](http://forums.asp.net/p/1589807/4025155.aspx) of this.